# Setting a default filter in Symfony API

Tags: symfony

I am seeking valuable resources and examples illustrating effective approaches for optimizing response filtering in Symfony, particularly when implementing default values, such as setting `isActive` to true.

Despite my attempts, the solutions I have devised so far exhibit sub-optimal performance. I have leveraged controllers, yet the data retrieval process has proven to be lengthy, requiring the use of normalizers to eventually generate a response. I would appreciate insights into more efficient strategies or code patterns to enhance the speed of response rendering in such scenarios.

Example:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\MasterList;

class MasterListController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/api/master_lists", name="get_active_master_lists", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function getActiveMasterLists(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MasterList::class);

        // Use the custom repository method to retrieve only active MasterLists
        $activeMasterLists = $repository->findActiveMasterLists();

        // Use Symfony Serializer to convert entities to array
        $serializedMasterLists = $serializer->normalize($activeMasterLists, null, [AbstractNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['masterList']]);

        // Return the serialized data as a JSON response
        return new JsonResponse($serializedMasterLists);
```

The response time for this operation is currently 5000ms, which is significantly high for the volume of data I am working with.

How differently would you do it? I have paginated my response, indexed `isActive` column in my table. I have tried caching and it is important to keep in mind my client requires one single response so he doesn't have to loop through multiple pages.

Comment: How many items are you getting. Have you thought of pagination ?

Comment: You have to use pagination.

Comment: yes, >= 1000 records minimum. I have allowed for pagination but the client requires a response without pagination. I have also indexed isActive on my tables. I have tried caching but this doesn't help since we have multiple users at any given time they are sending separate request to the api.

Comment: The speed to get a response only slowed down after the filter option was implemented

Comment: The client also does not want to loop through multiple pages for the results

Answer (score -1):

## Use Profiler

Use Symfony Profiler to debug your request : https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html

It will give you a lot of information. For example, you can see all queries run by Doctrine and time spend on each. You will also see memory consume during request.

## Fetching relations

If you see a lot of queries, maybe you fetch relations. Add ignore on you serialzer like you do with 'masterList' field. This will improve a lot the response time.

## Array Hydration

If you have a lot of rows to return in a single response, you can reduce time by using **Doctrine Array Hydration** : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes

Instead of return objects, Doctrine will return you a list of rows as array :

```php
[
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'bar', 'isActive' => 1],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'baz', 'isActive' => 1],
]
```

To **not return all columns** just specify it in select on your repository method.

Response from repository can be used in JsonResponse, you will not need to normalize data from `MasterList` to `array`.

Comment: I think array hydration has made the time for response worse

Answer (score -1):

I decided to push the whole operation to the database. create a view and render the response. This improved the speed of extraction considerably.